# Statsmodels OLS with rolling window problem

Tags: python, regression

I would like to do a regression with a rolling window, but I got only one parameter back after the regression:

```
 rolling_beta = sm.OLS(X2, X1, window_type='rolling', window=30).fit()
 rolling_beta.params
```

The result:

```
 X1    5.715089
 dtype: float64
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance, Roland

Comment: I don't see six months later that there is any indication that window_type='rolling' is part of the interface for statsmodels. Perhaps you checked this and it is evolving? A search on "window_type" reveals only a private function _window_ols.

Comment: Also, the answers to this and several similar questions are based on reformulating and calling sm.OLS independently each step. This is an inefficient way of doing rolling regression, something that is understood by statisticians -- see for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6920/efficient-online-linear-regression/6922 for refs. There is substantial economy in doing this using an updating methods (the whole Givens rotation thing). If you want turnkey, for the time being that mean shipping this to R which I appreciate may not work for your problem environment

Comment: @RolandSzarka As Eli S has pointed out, a , `window=30)` approach just does not seem to exist. So if my suggestion has helped you, would you consider marking it as the accepted answer? I see you have asked 7 questions by now and received many good suggestions, but still haven't accepted an answer once. Accepting answers is a good thing as it makes it easier for those looking for un-answered questions to provide help and suggestions.

Comment: @Roland Szarka How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the parameters `window_type='rolling'` and `window=30` simply do not do anything. First I'll show you why, and at the end I'll provide a setup I've got lying around for linear regressions on rolling windows.

---

**1.** The problem with your function:

Since you haven't provided some sample data, here's a function that returns a dataframe of a desired size with some random numbers:

```
# Function to build synthetic data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from collections import OrderedDict

def sample(rSeed, periodLength, colNames):

    np.random.seed(rSeed)
    date = pd.to_datetime("1st of Dec, 1999")   
    cols = OrderedDict()

    for col in colNames:
        cols[col] = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=periodLength)
    dates = date+pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(periodLength), 'D')

    df = pd.DataFrame(cols, index = dates)
    return(df)
```

Output:

```
X1        X2
2018-12-01 -1.085631 -1.294085
2018-12-02  0.997345 -1.038788
2018-12-03  0.282978  1.743712
2018-12-04 -1.506295 -0.798063
2018-12-05 -0.578600  0.029683
.
.
.
2019-01-17  0.412912 -1.363472
2019-01-18  0.978736  0.379401
2019-01-19  2.238143 -0.379176
```

Now, try:

```
rolling_beta = sm.OLS(df['X2'], df['X1'], window_type='rolling', window=30).fit()
rolling_beta.params
```

Output:

```
X1   -0.075784
dtype: float64
```

And this at least represents the structure of your output too, meaning that you're expecting an estimate for each of your sample windows, but instead you get a single estimate. So I looked around for some other examples using the same function online and in the statsmodels docs, but I was unable to find specific examples that actually worked. What I did find were a few discussions talking about how this functionality was deprecated a while ago. So then I tested the same function with some bogus input for the parameters:

```
rolling_beta = sm.OLS(df['X2'], df['X1'], window_type='amazing', window=3000000).fit()
rolling_beta.params
```

Output:

```
X1   -0.075784
dtype: float64
```

And as you can see, the estimates are the same, and no error messages are returned for the bogus input. So I suggest that you take a look at the function below. This is something I've put together to perform rolling regression estimates.

---

**2.** A function for regressions on rolling windows of a pandas dataframe

```
df = sample(rSeed = 123, colNames = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3'], periodLength = 50)

def RegressionRoll(df, subset, dependent, independent, const, win, parameters):
    """
    RegressionRoll takes a dataframe, makes a subset of the data if you like,
    and runs a series of regressions with a specified window length, and
    returns a dataframe with BETA or R^2 for each window split of the data.

    Parameters:
    ===========

    df: pandas dataframe
    subset: integer - has to be smaller than the size of the df
    dependent: string that specifies name of denpendent variable
    inependent: LIST of strings that specifies name of indenpendent variables
    const: boolean - whether or not to include a constant term
    win: integer - window length of each model
    parameters: string that specifies which model parameters to return:
                BETA or R^2

    Example:
    ========
        RegressionRoll(df=df, subset = 50, dependent = 'X1', independent = ['X2'],
                   const = True, parameters = 'beta', win = 30)

    """

    # Data subset
    if subset != 0:
        df = df.tail(subset)
    else:
        df = df

    # Loopinfo
    end = df.shape[0]
    win = win
    rng = np.arange(start = win, stop = end, step = 1)

    # Subset and store dataframes
    frames = {}
    n = 1

    for i in rng:
        df_temp = df.iloc[:i].tail(win)
        newname = 'df' + str(n)
        frames.update({newname: df_temp})
        n += 1

    # Analysis on subsets
    df_results = pd.DataFrame()
    for frame in frames:
        #print(frames[frame])

        # Rolling data frames
        dfr = frames[frame]
        y = dependent
        x = independent

        if const == True:
            x = sm.add_constant(dfr[x])
            model = sm.OLS(dfr[y], x).fit()
        else:
            model = sm.OLS(dfr[y], dfr[x]).fit()

        if parameters == 'beta':
            theParams = model.params[0:]
            coefs = theParams.to_frame()
            df_temp = pd.DataFrame(coefs.T)

            indx = dfr.tail(1).index[-1]
            df_temp['Date'] = indx
            df_temp = df_temp.set_index(['Date'])

        if parameters == 'R2':
            theParams = model.rsquared
            df_temp = pd.DataFrame([theParams])
            indx = dfr.tail(1).index[-1]
            df_temp['Date'] = indx
            df_temp = df_temp.set_index(['Date'])
            df_temp.columns = [', '.join(independent)]
        df_results = pd.concat([df_results, df_temp], axis = 0)

    return(df_results)


df_rolling = RegressionRoll(df=df, subset = 50, dependent = 'X1', independent = ['X2'], const = True, parameters = 'beta',
                                     win = 30)
```

Output: A dataframe with beta estimates for OLS of X2 on X1 for each 30 period window of the data.

```
const        X2
Date                          
2018-12-30  0.044042  0.032680
2018-12-31  0.074839 -0.023294
2019-01-01 -0.063200  0.077215
.
.
.
2019-01-16 -0.075938 -0.215108
2019-01-17 -0.143226 -0.215524
2019-01-18 -0.129202 -0.170304
```