# Rolling OLS using time as the independent variable with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to build a rolling OLS model in pandas, using a data frame/time series of stock prices. What I want to do is perform the OLS calculations over the last N days and return the predicted price and slope and add these in to their own respective columns in the data frame. As far as I can see my only option is to use `PandasRollingOLS` from `pyfinance` so I will use this in my example, but if there's another way I am happy to use that.

My data frame looks like this for example:

```
Date                     Price
....
2019-03-31 08:59:59.999  1660
2019-03-31 09:59:59.999  1657
2019-03-31 10:59:59.999  1656
2019-03-31 11:59:59.999  1652
2019-03-31 12:59:59.999  1646
2019-03-31 13:59:59.999  1645
2019-03-31 14:59:59.999  1650
2019-03-31 15:59:59.999  1669
2019-03-31 16:59:59.999  1674
```

I want to perform the rolling regression using the `Date` column as the independent variable. Ordinarily I would do:

```
X = df['Date']
y = df['Price']
model = ols.PandasRollingOLS(y, X, window=250)
```

However, unsurprisingly using `df['Date']` as my X returns an error.

So my first question is, what do I need to do to my `Date` column to get the `PandasRollingOLS` working. And my next question is what exactly do I need to call to return the predicted value and the slope? With a regular `OLS` I would do something like `model.predict` and `model.slope` but these options obviously aren't available with `PandasRollingOLS`.

I actually want to add these values to new columns in my df, so was thinking something like `df['Predict'] = model.predict` for example, but obviously that's not the answer. The ideal out come df would be this:

```
Date                     Price  Predict  Slope
....
2019-03-31 08:59:59.999  1660   1665     0.10
2019-03-31 09:59:59.999  1657   1663     0.10
2019-03-31 10:59:59.999  1656   1661     0.09
2019-03-31 11:59:59.999  1652   1658     0.08
2019-03-31 12:59:59.999  1646   1651     0.07
2019-03-31 13:59:59.999  1645   1646     0.07
2019-03-31 14:59:59.999  1650   1643     0.07
2019-03-31 15:59:59.999  1669   1642     0.07
2019-03-31 16:59:59.999  1674   1645     0.08
```

Any help would be really appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your dates to an integer using `datetime.datetime.strptime` and `time.mktime`, and then build models for desired subsets of your dataframe using `statsmodels` and a custom function to handle the rolling windows:

**Output:**

```
                         Price      Predict     Slope
Date                                                 
2019-03-31 10:59:59.999   1656  1657.670504  0.000001
2019-03-31 11:59:59.999   1652  1655.003830  0.000001
2019-03-31 12:59:59.999   1646  1651.337151  0.000001
2019-03-31 13:59:59.999   1645  1647.670478  0.000001
2019-03-31 14:59:59.999   1650  1647.003818  0.000001
2019-03-31 15:59:59.999   1669  1654.670518  0.000001
2019-03-31 16:59:59.999   1674  1664.337207  0.000001
```

**Code:**

```
#%%
# imports
import datetime, time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from collections import OrderedDict

# your data in a more easily reprodicible format
data = {'Date': ['2019-03-31 08:59:59.999', '2019-03-31 09:59:59.999', '2019-03-31 10:59:59.999',
        '2019-03-31 11:59:59.999',  '2019-03-31 12:59:59.999', '2019-03-31 13:59:59.999',
        '2019-03-31 14:59:59.999', '2019-03-31 15:59:59.999', '2019-03-31 16:59:59.999'],
        'Price': [1660, 1657, 1656, 1652, 1646, 1645, 1650, 1669, 1674]}

# function to make a useful time structure as independent variable
def myTime(date_time_str):
    date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    return(time.mktime(date_time_obj.timetuple()))

# add time structure to dataset
data['Time'] = [myTime(obs) for obs in data['Date']]

# time for pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function for rolling OLS of a desired window size on a pandas dataframe

def RegressionRoll(df, subset, dependent, independent, const, win):
    """
    RegressionRoll takes a dataframe, makes a subset of the data if you like,
    and runs a series of regressions with a specified window length, and
    returns a dataframe with BETA or R^2 for each window split of the data.

    Parameters:
    ===========
    df -- pandas dataframe
    subset -- integer - has to be smaller than the size of the df or 0 if no subset.
    dependent -- string that specifies name of denpendent variable
    independent -- LIST of strings that specifies name of indenpendent variables
    const -- boolean - whether or not to include a constant term
    win -- integer - window length of each model

    Example:
    ========
    df_rolling = RegressionRoll(df=df, subset = 0, 
                                dependent = 'Price', independent = ['Time'],
                                const = False, win = 3)

    """

    # Data subset
    if subset != 0:
        df = df.tail(subset)
    else:
        df = df

    # Loopinfo
    end = df.shape[0]+1
    win = win
    rng = np.arange(start = win, stop = end, step = 1)

    # Subset and store dataframes
    frames = {}
    n = 1

    for i in rng:
        df_temp = df.iloc[:i].tail(win)
        newname = 'df' + str(n)
        frames.update({newname: df_temp})
        n += 1

    # Analysis on subsets
    df_results = pd.DataFrame()
    for frame in frames:

    #debug
    #print(frames[frame])

    # Rolling data frames
    dfr = frames[frame]
    y = dependent
    x = independent

    # Model with or without constant
    if const == True:
        x = sm.add_constant(dfr[x])
        model = sm.OLS(dfr[y], x).fit()
    else:
        model = sm.OLS(dfr[y], dfr[x]).fit()

    # Retrieve price and price prediction
    Prediction = model.predict()[-1]
    d = {'Price':dfr['Price'].iloc[-1], 'Predict':Prediction}
    df_prediction = pd.DataFrame(d, index = dfr['Date'][-1:])

    # Retrieve parameters (constant and slope, or slope only)
    theParams = model.params[0:]
    coefs = theParams.to_frame()
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(coefs.T)
    df_temp.index = dfr['Date'][-1:]

    # Build dataframe with Price, Prediction and Slope (+constant if desired)
    df_temp2 = pd.concat([df_prediction, df_temp], axis = 1)
    df_temp2=df_temp2.rename(columns = {'Time':'Slope'})
    df_results = pd.concat([df_results, df_temp2], axis = 0)

return(df_results)

# test run
df_rolling = RegressionRoll(df=df, subset = 0, 
                            dependent = 'Price', independent = ['Time'],
                            const = False, win = 3)
print(df_rolling)
```

The code can easily be shortened by not specifying so many variables and rather put more expressions directly into dictionaries and functions, but we can take a look at that if the produced output does in fact represent your desired output. Also, you didn't specify whether or not to include a constant term in your analysis, so I've included an option to handle that too.

Comment: @top bantz Glad to help! Similar, but not identical, questions about rolling regression show up from time to time. One of the most interesting parts of your question was how to construct the desired output. You could also check out my post [Statsmodels OLS with rolling window problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152368/statsmodels-ols-with-rolling-window-problem/54308000#54308000) for a broader approach to your challenge that includes options for other parameters such as R^2.