# pandas dataframe rolling apply function using multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a function to a rolling window. I need to reference multiple columns from the dataframe to compute the output for the function.
Below is some sample code of what I am trying to do.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

d = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col1': range(0,10),
    'Col2': range(10,20),
    'Col3': range(20,30)
    })

func = lambda x: smf.ols('Col1 ~ Col2', data=x).fit().params[1]

d['Out'] = d.rolling(3).apply(func)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently implementation of `rolling` working with each column separately, so not possible sum 2 different columns.

You can test it by:

```
def func(x):
    print (x)
    return x.sum()

d.rolling(3).apply(func)
```

Comment: Any suggestions on an efficient way to accomplish the desired task?

Comment: @kav - Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: The lambda func I intend to use passes the inputs into another method. I've added some additional code the the question. Sorry for the confusion, was trying to keep initial question simple.

Comment: @kav - I guess you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152368/statsmodels-ols-with-rolling-window-problem)